# Multi-Thread in Colmap

Tags: linux, multithreading, machine-learning, computer-vision, colmap

While working on Colmap, I noticed that Colmap only utilizes a single core of my CPU and also uses less memory. Because of this, Colmap is taking so much time to produce the output. I also understand that when using multi-threads in Colmap, it loses data, so what I seek is a way to make Colmap utilize all my computer resources and produce lossless output.

I tried reconstructing 3D point cloud